Thinkpad not detecting monitor through docking station
I'm running LTS 24.04.01 on a Thinkpad X1
I have a docking station, so my keyboard and mouse and power are all plugged into the docking station. But my laptop can only see my monitor if I plug the HDMI cable in directly to the laptop. The docking station has a VGA port, not an HDMI port, but I'm not trying to run anything but the display so VGA should be sufficient.
This is my second laptop that I'm using with the docking station (Bought in 2017) and I've never figured out how to detect the monitor.
I'm not even sure where or how to start troubleshooting. It would be really nice to able to run the HDMI from the monitor to the docking station and only plug and unplug the USB-C cable.
I'm looking at All screens go blank when the PC is plugged to a docking station and Thinkpad not working with docking station but they don't seem to be the same issue.
Thinkpad not working with docking station  describes a kernel issue from 2019 that took a dock from working to not working. My laptop has never detected the display if it is attached to my dock.
And All screens go blank when the PC is plugged to a docking station describes a kernel issue from 2021 that was resolved in newer kernels.
I tried running lspci but there's nothing obvious in the output (or I have no idea what I'm looking for):
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P 6p+8e cores Host Bridge/DRAM Controller
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 04)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCIe 4.0 Graphics Port
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0
00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #2
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake Crashlog and Telemetry (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0
00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #1
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake AMT SOL Redirection (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: KIOXIA Corporation NVMe SSD Controller XG8 (rev 01)

Running  ubuntu-drivers devices returns this:
udevadm hwdb is deprecated. Use systemd-hwdb instead.
== /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id ==
modalias : dmi:bvnLENOVO:bvrN3XET50W(1.25):bd01/25/2024:br1.25:efr1.19:svnLENOVO:pn21HMCTO1WW:pvrThinkPadX1CarbonGen11:rvnLENOVO:rn21HMCTO1WW:rvrNotDefined:cvnLENOVO:ct10:cvrNone:skuLENOVO_MT_21HM_BU_Think_FM_ThinkPadX1CarbonGen11:
vendor   : Lenovo
model    : product_version
driver   : oem-sutton-akando-meta - third-party fr

